# Jenkins behind an Apache with mod_proxy

Tags: apache, continuous-integration, jenkins, mod-proxy

I followed the instructions and the reverse proxy with Apache in front of Jenkins does not work. I have set up an Apache virtualhost config that proxies to Jenkins:

## Apache virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:8084>
    ServerAdmin emil@my_email.com
    ProxyRequests     Off
    ProxyPass         /jenkins  http://localhost:8084/jenkins
    ProxyPassReverse  /jenkins  http://localhost:8084/jenkins
    <Proxy http://localhost:8084/jenkins*>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
     </Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost on
 </VirtualHost>
```

The virtualhost is activated, no errors.

You can see my changes to /etc/default/jenkins here:

```
HTTP_PORT=8084
...
PREFIX=/jenkins
...
JENKINS_ARGS="--httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1 --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --prefix=$PREFIX --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --ajp13Port=$AJP_PORT"
```

I am tailing the apache logs and jenkins, but when I try to access http://:8084/jenkins, I get nothing, no page. When I start Jenkins without --httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1, I open http://:8084/jenkins successfully, but this is directly accessing Jenkins, does not pass through Apache.

Any ideas what might be the problem in my reverse proxy config? It is pretty standard.

Thanks,

Emil

Answer (score 2):

I had forgotten to put a "Listen 8084" directive in ports.conf, so Apache was not listening there. Anyway, solved, shouldn't do setups on Friday evening.

Comment: When I am making the same config and start apache and hitting the jenkins url, infinite number of apache2 tasks get created ... Can you please help me ?